# Is this incorrect use or bad practice of class loaders?

Tags: java, class, classloader

My program is designed to launch from a runnable jar file, set everything up if needs be, and then load a class in another jar file to initiate the program. This allows for self updating, restarts, etc. Well, the class loading code I have seems a bit funky to me. Below is the code I am using to do load the program. Is this incorrect use or bad practice?

```
    try {
        Preferences.userRoot().put("clientPath", Run.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().toString()); //Original client location; helps with restarts
    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Preferences.userRoot().flush();
    } catch (BackingStoreException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    File file = new File(path); // path of the jar we will be launching to initiate the program outside of the Run class
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = file.toURI().toURL(); // converts the file path to a url
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    URL[] urls = new URL[] { url };
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

    Class cls = null;
    try {
        cls = cl.loadClass("com.hexbit.EditorJ.Load"); // the class we are loading to initiate the program
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        cls.newInstance();  // starts the class that has been loaded and the program is on its way
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem you have is that when you get an Exception you pretend that logging the exception makes it ok to continue as if nothing happened.

If you aggregate the try/catch blocks, your code will be much shorter and easier to read, and it won't assume that exceptions don't really matter.

Try this example

```
public static Object load(String path, String className) {
    try {
        URL url = new File(path).toURI().toURL();
        ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { url });
        return cl.loadClass(className).newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to load "+className+" " + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Putting it in a try block like that seems a little generic, but you can get the type of the exception from Exception e, correct?

Comment: @StevenTylerFrizell correct, the action you take is the same in every case so you don't need different handlers for them all.